# How can I record the framerate within a program over time?

Tags: framerate

I need to measure the framerate of a program over time to see how the computer's hardware affects the program's performance. I know that common screen recording software display the framerate, but I want to write the values over time to a file, so I can plot a graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fraps does that

> Fraps will show a maximum framerate of 9999 fps on screen. If you need to know precise framerates above this you must use benchmarking and find out the value from FRAPSLOG.TXT, or from the detailed statistics (if you have this option enabled).

http://www.fraps.com/faq.php

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know fraps had this feature.